# Twilio outgoing call id

Tags: javascript, php, api, twilio

Please i need some help.

I have been reading about this API Twilio , because a have to solve some code that I didn't do.

And it is working on a page in PHP, to make calls to customers. There is a process that runs every often and check the log or cvs and inserts a record in the database with info Twilio.

Ideally, if at the end of the outgoing call, it could be know the unique ID of the call and save it along with some comments.

How can I take the parameters of the client-side call ? or there is other way? (duration, Sid, to, etc)

I already read this, but I don't get it

Thanks!!

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call

```
<?php 
require_once('Services/Twilio.php'); // Loads the library
$API_VERSION = '2010-04-01';
$accountSid = 'AC7d3444f83611xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$authToken  = 'd72d5f036e96abexxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

$capability = new Services_Twilio_Capability($accountSid, $authToken);
$capability->allowClientOutgoing('AP29cb5d9e0dcxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
$capability->allowClientIncoming('name');
$token = $capability->generateToken();
//error_log("token is $token");
?>

<script type="text/javascript">     
      Twilio.Device.setup("<?php echo $token; ?>");     
      function call() {         
      params = {"PhoneNumber": $("#number_no").val(), "callerid": $("#callerid").val(), "agent_id": $("#agent_id").val(), "lead_id": $("#lead_id").val()};
      Twilio.Device.connect(params);
      }     
      function hangup() {           
        Twilio.Device.disconnectAll();
        //Twilio.Device.disconnect();
      }       
  </script>
```

This code is called when you update something

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.call_status').change(function()
    {
        var status = $(this).val();
        var rec_val = $(this).parent().find('.rec_val').val();
        var pledge_amt = $('#pledge_amt'+rec_val).val();
        hangup();
    $.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo site_url('agent/agent_status/'); ?>',
    type: 'post',
    data: {'rec_val': rec_val, 'status': status, 'pledge_amt': pledge_amt},
    success:function(resp)
    {
        if(resp)
        {
            window.location.href="<?php echo site_url('agent/call_leads/'); ?>";
            //$('.msg').html("Status Updated Successfully!").fadeOut(5000);

        } else 
            {
             alert('Please check your selected data');
            }
    },
    error:function(resp)
    {
        alert(resp);
    }
    });

    });
    jQuery('.status_update').fadeOut(5000);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hello, Let me know if you are  implementing twilio first time. may be i can help you . also i would like to check your current code

Comment: It is my first time with Twilio, I just trying to solving a issue in someone else code.

Comment: This is the Browser call feature buddy.

Comment: https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/client/outgoing-calls


check this link and follow the steps. Its very useful , and let me know still you dont get anything.

Also check this   : https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/client/browser-to-browser-calls

Comment: Thanks for helping out @PunitGajjar!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you [create the call, you get a connection object](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/device#connect). The [connection object contains all the parameters](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/connection#parameters) that you have read about in the REST API documentation regarding making calls. You can get the Call SID (it's unique ID) this way. In the code below, I use the `connection` object created when placing the call to log out the parameters of the call:

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
      Twilio.Device.setup("<?php echo $token; ?>");     
      function call() {         
          params = {"PhoneNumber": $("#number_no").val(), "callerid": $("#callerid").val(), "agent_id": $("#agent_id").val(), "lead_id": $("#lead_id").val()};
          var connection = Twilio.Device.connect(params);
          console.log(connection.parameters);
      }     
  </script>
```

Let me know if this helps!

**Edit:**

To use this connection in the hangup function you need to save the connection object outside of the scope of the call function. You could do that by defining the `currentConnection` as a variable outside of the two functions and then setting and using it when the actions take place. See the updated code below (check out the comments for more info):

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
      Twilio.Device.setup("<?php echo $token; ?>");
      // define currentConnection here, but don't set it to anything.
      var currentConnection = null;

      function call() {         
          params = {"PhoneNumber": $("#number_no").val(), "callerid": $("#callerid").val(), "agent_id": $("#agent_id").val(), "lead_id": $("#lead_id").val()};
          // create and set the currentConnection
          currentConnection = Twilio.Device.connect(params);
          console.log(currentConnection.parameters);
      }

      function hangup() {
        console.log("Do stuff with parameters");
        console.log(currentConnection.parameters)
        Twilio.Device.disconnectAll();

        // reset currentConnection until the next call is made
        currentConnection = null;
      } 
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @philnash , but how I am noob in js how can i take this value in function hangup()

Comment: I've edited the answer with some more detail. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: i think that doesn't work .. TypeError: currentConnection is null in function hangup

Comment: Sorry, or even better, can i pass one or two parameters to a window.open ?

Comment: Hooray! Glad you're getting there with it! Please do mark the answer as correct if it helped. Thanks!